# Installing Biomethyl package R Untar2 error

Tags: installation, package, rstudio

I am attempting to install the Biomethyl package as part of a Bioinformatics internship I am working on. However I cannot seem to install the package properly. Having looked for answers over the last few days and failed, I turn to you guys.
Overall, the error I cannot seem to fix is the untar2 error (shown below)

I tried a wide variety of solutions, none of which worked.
Non-coding solutions that were attempted are the following:

i) Changing the directory of the package, locations ranged from desktop, to documents, and in the R folder itself

ii) Completely uninstalling R and RStudio as well as re-downloading the package

iii)Manually extract components of the package (failed miserably)

iv)Contacting the creator, this led me to see that my version of R (3.6) is not the issue. However this problem seems to be isolated to myself as he has not heard of similar problems from other users. Through this interaction, I also believe that there is no issue with the downloaded file.

v)Disabling all other computer functions that may have interfered with files being created or added, basically disabled my BitDefender, even if all proper authorizations were given to R and Rstudio.

As for the code, this is the code that should work as provided by the creator's github ( https://github.com/yuewangpanda/BioMethyl )

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/yohan/OneDrive/Documents/R/BioMethyl-master/BioMethyl_1.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
```

Which resulted in the following error

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/yohan/OneDrive/Documents/R/BioMethyl-master/BioMethyl_1.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/yohan/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : 
  incomplete block on file
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/yohan/OneDrive/Documents/R/BioMethyl-master/BioMethyl_1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Along with this, I tried swapping around the slashes, doubling them up, inverting their orientation (front slash instead of backslash).

I also tried adding type="source" which resulted in the same error.

Additionally, I tried to run the code directly into the console, again, it did not work.

Lastly, I tried installing it directly from the github repo and not from the downloaded file, but this was not possible due to privacy limitations on the github repo.

I thank you in advance for your help, also, if there are any issues with the question format please let me know and I will edit them accordingly.

Additional information:

OS: Windows 10

R Version:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.0                         
year           2019                        
month          04                          
day            26                          
svn rev        76424                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
nickname       Planting of a Tree
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out, i'll leave the answer here in case anyone else encounters this problem.

The issue seems to be downloading the repository as a whole, if you download the .tar.gz file in its unzipped format, it will work (at least it did for me)

This is the exact link from which I downloaded my copy of the file that worked for me.

https://github.com/yuewangpanda/BioMethyl/blob/ffcba473a3b12a159ce2dfdaf63c4f63d84b40ef/BioMethyl_1.1.tar.gz

Best of Luck

Y.Lefol